# How do you tell when the points on a 3D plot lie on a plane or on a curve?

Tags: python, r, geometry, data-science

I have a 3D scatter plot of some data generated using matploblib Axes 3D. I need to decide if it lies on a plane or a curve. I am trying to understand the visual differences that would indicate plane or curve. My guess is that if there are points along a wide range of z values then it lies on a curve because if it lied a plane, this would mean that the points are spread only over a flat surface. Even if my guess is correct, I am only right by virtue of eliminating the only other possibility so how would I tell specifically if it the data lies on a curve?

Answer (score 2):

If the plane is tilted you will also find a wide range of z values.

Assuming you have your 3D `points` in an nx3 array, you can calculate the plane that fits them using this:

```
centroid = np.mean(points, axis=0)
_, eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.svd(points - centroid, full_matrices=False)
normal = eigenvectors[2]
dispersion = eigenvalues[2]
```

The plane that best approximates the scattered points is defined by a point (`centroid`) and its `normal` vector.

Then, according to the `dispersion` value along the normal axis you can decide whether it is low enough (the points lie on a plane) or it is too high (they don't lie on a plane).